# Barajas De Letras para juego de memoria

Tags: c

El ejercicio consta de hacer un grupo de letras con su pareja decir: AA BB
entonces ¿como puedo hacer que una misma letra  no se repita mas de cuatro veces o tres? ya llevo un poco de adelanto con el codigo solo que tiene algun problema con la parte de verificar si se repite las letras de 3 a 4 veces

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int main (){   
    int diccionario[27]= "LDFGHJKQWERTYUIOPXZACVBNM" 
    char  Baraja[6][7];
    int i = 0,j = 0;
    char l1,l2;
      int contador = 0, num = 0;
     int Repetidos;
```

Con esta parte del codigo es con la que lleno la matriz Baraja con las letras

```
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
        for(int j = 2; j < 8; j += 2){  
         l1 = '7';
         l2 = '9';
          while(l1 != l2){   
            l1 = rand() % 25 + 65;
            l2 = rand() % 25 + 65;    
             }
             Baraja[i][j - 2] = l1;      
             Baraja[i][j - 1 ] = l2;         
          }
        }
```

Esta parte del codigo se encargaria de verificar si el caracter se repite pero no se por que no me funciona para explicar un poco mejor esta parte se repetira hasta que termine de recorrer todo el array de num a base de las condiciones hasta que no se recorra Baraja completamente, num no va a aumentar si llega el caso de que se recorre Baraja num aumenta y el Valor de i y j vuelven a 0

```
     while(num < 26){   
                   if(diccionario[num] == Baraja[i][j]){
                    Repetidos = Baraja[i][j];
                    contador++;
                 
                   if(contador == 4){
                    printf("%c - %d //",Repetidos,contador);
                
                  }
                 }
                  if(i == 5){
                    num++;
                    i = 0;
                 }  
                  if(j == 4){
                    j = 0;
                    i++;
                  }
                 
                 j++;
                 
                  }
```

Esta parte se encarga de mostrar la matriz Baraja

```
   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
        printf("\n\n\n");
        
        for( int  j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            
            printf(" \t");  
             printf("%c",Baraja[i][j]);  
  
        
            }
        }
        

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? Me he leído el hilo dos veces y no he encontrado ninguna pregunta

Comment: La pregunta es, cómo hago que una pareja no se repita más de tres o cuatro veces decir una pareja: AA no me salga AAAA

Comment: Creo que lo que tienes allí es sólo un error de impresión. A como puedo ver en la salida del programa lo que hace es  filas de 5 columnas cada fila. Si sólo quieres parejas de letras, haz que guarde la letra 1 y la letra 2 en un mismo array. Mandas a imprimir más letras de las que debes, y no haces los saltos de línea correctos

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas el código que tienes para comprobar si las letras están repetidas. Lo único que tenía tu código era un error con el tamaño del array Baraja[6][2], las dimensiones del arreglo hacían que las letras se repitieran más de dos veces cada una. Y recuerda que los números random son pseudo aleatorios.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
char diccionario[27]= "LDFGHJKQWERTYUIOPXZACVBNM";
char  Baraja[6][2];
int i = 0,j = 0;
char l1,l2;
int contador = 0, num = 0;
int Repetidos;

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for(int j = 2; j < 8; j += 2) {
        l1 = '7';
        l2 = '9';
        while(l1 != l2) {
            l1 = l2 = rand() % 25 + 65;

        }
        Baraja[i][j - 2] = l1;
        Baraja[i][j - 1 ] = l2;
    }
}


for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("\n\n\n");

    for( int  j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        printf(" \t");
        printf("%c",Baraja[i][j]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Si, pero si quiero que el array siga aumentando de tamaño como hago que no se repita las pareja de una letra  de 3 a 4 veces?

Comment: Simplemente haces el tamaño del arreglo más grande. en char  Baraja[6][2]; puedes hacer que Baraja[20][2]. Tenga 20 elementos en las filas. Generando Números aleatorios siempre las parejas se van a repetir, ya que los números no son completamente aleatorios.

Comment: Ya veo y si quiero aumentar las columnas?

Comment: Simplemente aumentas el tamaño de las columnas del arreglo: Baraja[20][10]. SI la respuesta te fue de utilidad podrías marcarla como correcta.